# Windows 10 LAN or WiFi networking gets 169.xxx address on DHCP or static

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dhcp, tcpip

Surface Pro 4. Windows 10 1709 16299.251

Looking at the above device for a friend. When connecting to network on WiFi it asks for key instantly, and when type in, attempts to connect and then comes back with a "No internet - secured" message. An IPCONFIG shows it has a 169.xxx address. If I config the IPv4 manually with correct details there is still no internet and I can't ping the device. Multiple other devices working on network.

Plugging in a ethernet dongle the same behaviour is exhibited on LAN so believe it's a Windows issue or some sort as discounted adaptor.

- I have tried removing all adaptors/protocols and reinstalled / rebooted
- Reset winsock via cmd
- Reset tcpip via cmd
- Disabled firewall
- Disabled AV
- Ran malware scanner

Any ideas?

**Edit** So I download the Windows 10 iso and performed a repair install. This resolved the issue.

**Edit 2** Adding in case anyone has similar issues. Windows then updates and breaks the networking again. It's either KB4088776 or KB4058043 that kills it. Annoying that this is on a Surface! - not sure how to proceed now

Comment: Is MAC address filtering set up on the router such that devices have to be allowed?

Comment: No - unrestricted and doesn't work on multiple networks -however see edit!

Comment: Well done, but does Windows update manage to break it again???

Comment: Just came to update for anyone searching in the future... yes it does. Not sure how to proceed now...

Comment: Does KB4099950 fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the AV. In my case it was the AVAST Firewall Service. Disabling AV did not help. Required a full uninstall.

Comment: This worked perfectly.